# Network Error in Blazor WebAssembly site with ASP.Net Core Identity login link

Tags: asp.net, identityserver4, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my BlazorWebAssembly + ASP.NET Core Identity test site (.NET 5.0 RC1), I'm getting the following error when trying to log in.

> There was an error trying to log you in: 'Network Error'

I have already set appsettings OIDC to be the following:

```
{
  "SiteName": "MyProject",
  "oidc": {
    "Authority": "https://167.172.118.170/",
    "ClientId": "MyProject",
    "DefaultScopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "/",
    "RedirectUri": "https://167.172.118.170/authentication/login-callback",
    "ResponseType": "code"
  }
}
```

Why is it not able to connect?

Test site is at http://167.172.118.170/ and the code can be found in https://github.com/jonasarcangel/BlazorLoginNetworkErrorIssue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear by now that Blazor uses the internal url `http://localhost:5008` as the authority instead of the external url `http://167.172.118.170/`

When the client attempts to connect to `http://localhost:5008/.well-known/openid-configuration`, an error occurs: connection refused...

As a matter of fact the client should use this url: `http://167.172.118.170/.well-known/openid-configuration`, but it does not as the value of the authority is determined by Blazor.

If you type the url `http://167.172.118.170/.well-known/openid-configuration` in the browser's address bar, you'll see all the configuration information about the Identity Provider. Indeed, `http://167.172.118.170/` is the authority. But as you've seen setting the Authority to this url in the appsettings.json file was simply ignored, and the internal url was used instead.

How to solve this ? We should tell Blazor not to use the internal url but the external one...

Attempts suggested:

In the web server project's Startup class's ConfigureService change this code:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
           .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationIdentityDbContext> 
            ();
```

To

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.IssuerUri = "https://167.172.118.170/";
               
            })
              .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, 
                                ApplicationIdentityDbContext>();
```

2. [Use the ForwardedHeaders middleware](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides/). [See this sample](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/rel/1.1.0/samples/HttpOverridesSample/Startup.cs#L13-L16) as to how to do it.
3. Stick to the above... The issue is here, and not somewhere else.

Good luck...

Comment: This change worked: https://github.com/jonasarcangel/BlazorLoginNetworkErrorIssue/commit/399beb807acb4a8f8c28267fe37d8e8df376226b Now the issue is it is using localhost to redirect to the login screen.

Comment: Perhaps you should also change to: client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://167.172.118.170/")); instead of the current definition. there are Two changes to make. Why do you use "http" instead of https ?

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work. It might be needing some other configuration.

Comment: How is this file generated? http://167.172.118.170/.well-known/openid-configuration How can I configure the result?

Comment: Implemented all the suggestions you have provided, but still getting the issue.  https://github.com/jonasarcangel/BlazorLoginNetworkErrorIssue/blob/master/src/MyProject.Data.Identity/Extensions.cs https://github.com/jonasarcangel/BlazorLoginNetworkErrorIssue/blob/master/src/MyProject.Web.Server/Startup.cs

Comment: This solution worked.

using IdentityServer4.Extensions;
//...
app.Use((ctx, next) => 
{
    ctx.SetIdentityServerOrigin("http://167.172.118.170");
    return next();
});

Comment: Glad to hear that... I've learned a great deal from attempting to find a solution... And from the look and design of your application; The Identity UI looks great and is cleverly integrated with the other parts of the app.

Answer (score 1):

I just test and the url *http://167.172.118.170/_configuration/BlazorWorld.Web.Client* returns

```js
{
    "authority": "http://localhost:5008",
    "client_id": "BlazorWorld.Web.Client",
    "redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5008/authentication/login-callback",
    "post_logout_redirect_uri": "http://localhost:5008/authentication/logout-callback",
    "response_type": "code",
    "scope": "BlazorWorld.Web.ServerAPI openid profile"
}
```

Then the app try to connect to *http://localhost:5008/.well-known/openid-configuration* :

So the deployed appsettings is probably not the good one.

[image]

Comment: Appsettings are now correct after deploying everything from scratch. I'm still seeing the error though.

Comment: http://167.172.118.170/_configuration/MyProject.Web.Client

Comment: Ok but http://167.172.118.170/_configuration/BlazorWorld.Web.Client is still returning the same document